# problem with intel 82865 motherboard graphic driver in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, aero, igp

I have cpu with Pentium 4 3GHz processor. My motherboard is Intel 82865. I have installed the graphic driver for intel 82865 by using the graphic driver of Windows XP and changing the program's compatibility to Windows XP SP2. I got many thing ok with that.

For example many resolutions and I can also play GTA. But what I want to know is why I cant view Aero and transparency effect in windows 7. It says contact the manufacturer for compbatible WDDM graphic driver.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 requires a WDDM graphic driver for Aero to work, there is not one available for that graphics chip, nothing you can do with that graphics chip to make it work with Aero, sorry.

http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-030907.htm

Comment: There's one thing they can do, get a 3rd party video adapter. :)